# How to solve Invalid Hook Call error when using Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new at coding and I'm having the following error when adding a MaterialUI Icon

```
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';


function Header() {
    return (

<div>
<PersonIcon />
<h2>Header file</h2>



</div>

    );
}

export default Header;
```

When adding  I get the following error:

[image: Console Error when adding]

Please notice that I have installed MaterialUI Core and also MaterialUI Icons
When not adding  everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
npm uninstall @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

Then

```
npm i @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```

Restart the React server

```
npm start
// OR
yarn start
```

**Let me know if it works, Good Luck**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your app in `ThemeProvider`:

index.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import App from './App';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
  },
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```